# how to insert mock object into an object while it has no method to insert?

Tags: java, powermock

i have such code:

```
public class A {
    int n;
    public A() {
        n = 10;
    } 
    public int get() {
        B b = new B(...);
        return b.getValue() + n;
    }
}
```

now i want to unit test get(), but the constructor of B is very complicated, so i want to mock B, then there is a problem here, after i mock B, it has no method the set the mock object into A, so any body has good idea?

Comment: "it has no method the set the mock object into A" - Add one? Not an option, I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powermock you can mock the construction of the B instance.

First, you need to annotate your class:

`@PrepareForTest(A.class)`

then create the mock and record the behaviour:

```
B bMock = createMock(B.class);
expectNew(B.class, "someargument").andReturn(bMock);
expect(bMock.getValue()).andReturn(something);

replay(bMock, B.class);
verify(bMock, B.class);
```

Read the [full docs](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

Comment: OK, I am missing something. In the OP's implementation, the instance of B is a local variable in `get()`. You described how to mock B. But I am missing the part, where you tell A to use the mock in `get()` ... Is this done by the annotation? (Sorry, not familiar with Powermock)

Comment: This is done by `expectNew` - it returns the mock when you create an instance. So when `A` does `new B()`, it'll return the mock.

Answer (score 3):

If you setup the class like this:

```
public class A {
 int n;
 public A() {
     n = 10;
 } 
 public int get() {
    return getValueFromB() + n;
 }
 protected int getValueFromB()
 {
    return new B().getValue();
 }
}
```

you could mock getValueFromB(). Now get() relies on getValueFromB(), which is mocked and can be implemented later.